# How to setup a Sockect.io server in aws EC2 and then connect remotely to the server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sockets, amazon-ec2, socket.io

Good morning.
I created a simple server for a chat using Socket.io.  In the next screen, which would be the client interface, you can see some inputs

[image]

In localhost, in my computer works fine. Here are the logs messages from the server:

[image]

I uploaded the server to an EC2 instance with ubuntu. And it work fine, in the same way

[image]

Logs from the server in EC2

[image]

The main problem is when I tried to connect from my computer to the Socket.io server in EC2.  I got this error from my client side file in  my computer:

> socket.io.js:3888 GET
> https://mydomain:80/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NQB59WG

Here is my server code:

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const socketio = require("socket.io");
const app = express();



app.set('port', 3000);

//static files

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

//start the server
const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {

    console.log("server on port", app.get('port'));
});

const io = socketio(server);

//websockects

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    console.log("new connection  " + socket.id);

    socket.on('chat:message', (data) => {
        console.log(data);

        io.sockets.emit("chat:server", data);

    });

    socket.on('chat:typing', (data) => {
        console.log(data);

        socket.broadcast.emit("chat:typing", data);

    });
});
```

Here is my client code:

```
const socket = io("https://domain:80");

//dom elements
let message = document.getElementById("message");
let username = document.getElementById("username");
let btn = document.getElementById("button");
let output = document.getElementById("output");
let actions = document.getElementById("actions");


btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log({
        username: username.value,
        message: message.value
    });

    socket.emit("chat:message", {
        username: username.value,
        message: message.value
    });
});

message.addEventListener('keypress', function() {
    socket.emit("chat:typing", username.value);
});


socket.on("chat:server", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    actions.innerHTML = "";
    output.innerHTML += "<p><strong>" + data.username + "</strong>: " + data.message + " </p>";

});


socket.on("chat:typing", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    actions.innerHTML = "<p><strong>" + data + "</strong> esta escribiendo </p>";

});
```

And here are the instance inboud rules for ports:

[image]

When i tried to connect from my computer to the EC2 instance, I tried with several ways to connect, like this:

const socket = io("https://url.org:80");

const socket = io("https://url.org");

const socket = io("https://ipaddres:80");

const socket = io("https://ipaddres");

const socket = io("ec2-xxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com");

const socket = io("ec2-xxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:80");

Nothing works,  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to do two things:

1. I use my domaind without port

const socket = io("https://url.org");

2. The EC2 Instance work with nginx, I modified the header to add this property:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

And it worked